# Lucene index deleted when opening with Luke/Indexreader

Tags: lucene, lucene.net, luke

I was creating a lucene index when my indexing program crashed. The indexer had processed about 3M documents before crashing, producing a 14GB file. When I opened the index in Luke (with force unlock), the whole index was gone!. poof.

The opened index had 0 documents and its size was reduced to 1kb. Did anyone experience this, or can offer an explanation

(Using Lucene.Net 2.9)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably, your indexing code never called `commit()` before crashing. If you don't want to lose all your changes, you should call `commit()` every `X` added documents.